# .bat to relaunch Steam.exe when it crashes

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, crash, steam

My Steam crashes periodically due to HDD issues I plan to resolve at a later date. In the meantime, I'd like a solution to automatically re-open Steam when it closes so my download may continue.

So far, from someone's suggestion, I've tried

```
@echo on

:Restart start "Steam" /wait "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steam.exe"

goto restart
```

However, this just seems to loop restart constantly and never opens Steam at all.
Not sure where I messed up...

Answer (score 0):

This might be easier to accomplish running steam under Task Scheduler. On the settings tab there is an option restart the task if it fails.

There is also software that would allow running steam as a service (freeware, or srvany from the Windows resource kit).  The service is then configured to interact with the desktop and to automatically restart on a failure.